# VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When running a python program involving the following function, `image[x,y] = 0`  gives the following error message. What does that mean and how to solve it? Thanks.

Warning

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer   
will result in an error in the future
image[x,y] = 0
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Code

```
def create_image_and_label(nx,ny):
  x = np.floor(np.random.rand(1)[0]*nx)
  y = np.floor(np.random.rand(1)[0]*ny)

  image = np.ones((nx,ny))
  label = np.ones((nx,ny))
  image[x,y] = 0
  image_distance = ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt(image)

  r = np.random.rand(1)[0]*(r_max-r_min)+r_min
  plateau = np.random.rand(1)[0]*(plateau_max-plateau_min)+plateau_min

  label[image_distance <= r] = 0 
  label[image_distance > r] = 1
  label = (1 - label)

  image_distance[image_distance <= r] = 0 
  image_distance[image_distance > r] = 1
  image_distance = (1 - image_distance)*plateau

  image = image_distance + np.random.randn(nx,ny)/sigma

  return image, label[92:nx-92,92:nx-92]
```

Comment: Which versions of `numpy`/`scipy`?

Comment: I just tested it, the numpy version is 1.11.0; the scipy version is 0.17.1

Comment: `np.floor` gives you a float but indexing will only be possible with integers in the future. So you get a deprecation warning that a version upgrade of `numpy` will break your code in the future. But this warning should not result in an error. Have you tried this part in isolation, meaning only the creation of the `image` array and setting one element to zero?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The warning is saying not to use floats to index your array; use `np.int` instead of `np.floor`